# rsyslogd does not write data to logfile when configured with TLS

Tags: rsyslog

I'm trying to set up rsyslog with TLS to forward specific records from `/var/log/auth.log` from host A to a remote server B.

The configuration file I wrote for rsyslog is the following:

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/licensing/certificates/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/licensing/certificates/client-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/licensing/certificates/client-key.pem


$InputFilePollInterval 10
#Read from the auth.log file and assign the tag "ssl-auth" for its messages
input
        (type="imfile"
         File="/var/log/auth.log"
         reopenOnTruncate="on"
         deleteStateOnFileDelete="on"
         Tag="ssl-auth")

$template auth_log, "  %msg% "


# Send ssl traffic to server on port 514
if ($syslogtag == 'ssl-auth') then{action
                                        (type="omfwd"
                                         protocol="tcp"
                                         target="<ip@server>"
                                         port="514"
                                         template="auth_log"
                                         StreamDriver="gtls"
                                         StreamDriverMode="1"
                                         StreamDriverAuthMode="x509/name"
                                        )}
```

Using this configuration, when I try to ssh-login the first time into the host A from another host X everything works fine; the file `/var/log/auth.log` is written and the tcpdump shows traffic towards server B.

But from then on, it does not work anymore.
Even if I try to exit from host A and login back again whenever I do, the file `/var/log/auth.log` is not ever written and no traffic appears over tcpdump.

The very strange things is that if I remove the TLS from the configuration it works.

Comment: I'm having problems understanding your question/problem. Are you able to send the logs but unable to receive them? - Then what does your config of the receiving syslog server look like? // Have you copied the certificates to both client and server?

Comment: @eDonkey thank you for your interest in my question but I solved the problem I was doing some mistakes in the configuration but I wasn't able to identify them

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that! Please share your gained knowledge in an answer. It may help future users encountering the same problem.